# Cakephp 3.1 Force SSL on Shared Hosting

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, cakephp

I am trying to use SSL on my cakephp 3.1 website but I always ends up with redirect loops. 
My website is on a shared hosting server. I have configured it as follow:

```
├───public_html
├───.htaccess (1)
├───website
│   ├───.htacess(2)
│   └───webroot
│       └─── .htaccess(3)
```

In my root .htaccess (1) in the public_html folder I added the following to set my document root

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !website/webroot/
RewriteRule (.*) /website/webroot/$1 [L]
```

My second .htaccess (2) in the website dir looks like the following

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and the last .htaccess in the cakephp webroot folder is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

So basically the only thing I've added is the public_html .htaccess to set my document root, other files i did not touch

To force SSL I've added the following to the pubic_html .htaccess file (1)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But still no luck. No matter what I do I either ends up with redirect loop or the site just break down.

Help please :)

Comment: Do you control the web server? There is rewrite logging that you can enable to help track this down. Also, have you looked at the sequence of requests generated, with a debugging console in your browser? There might be a pattern to the loop that gives you (or us) some hint of what's going wrong.

Comment: Thanks Greg for the quick response. I have limited access to the server, its a shared hosting. If I was able to modify apache configurations, it would make my life easier but sadly I can't. Thus I am using .htaccess. 
I will try to look the requests sequence and update this post if I found something.